# React MUI Pagination causing overflow in MUI Navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I was using mui react components and everything was working fine till i added pagination component and it started to overflow the toolbox of mui navbar except this everything is fine

I've tried removing all the css for both and even tried using the direct mui pagination api but nothing works and i'm not sure what is causing this issue.

i would be glad if anyone let me know what is the issue with this code

**APPBAR CODE**

```
return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar style={{backgroundColor: "#FF005C"}} position="fixed">
        <Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }} >

          <Stack direction="row" style={{'cursor': 'pointer'}} alignItems="center" onClick={()=> window.scroll(0,0)} >
          {/* <Link href="/trending" color="inherit" underline="none" > */}
              
          <LocalMoviesOutlinedIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'block' }, mr: 0.7 }} />

          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
          >
            Tvision
          </Typography>

          {/* </Link> */}
          </Stack>
          <div className="seach-box-area">
          <Search>
            <SearchIconWrapper>
              <SearchIcon />
            </SearchIconWrapper>
            <StyledInputBase className="seach-box-searcher"
              placeholder="Search…"
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </Search>
          </div>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
          <IconButton size="large" aria-label="Trending" color="inherit">
                <Link href="/trending" color="inherit" underline="none" > <WhatshotIcon /> </Link>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton size="large" aria-label="Movies" color="inherit">
                
                <Link href="/movies" color="inherit" underline="none" > <MovieIcon /> </Link>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="TV Series"
              color="inherit"
            >
                <Link href="/series" color="inherit" underline="none" > <LiveTvIcon /> </Link>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
    </Box>
  );
```

**REST OF THE PAGE CODE**

```
return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="trending-text"> <span> <LocalFireDepartmentIcon color='warning' fontSize='inherit'/> </span> Trending Now </h1>
            
            <div className="trending">

            {content && content.map((c)=>(
                <ContentCard 
                key={c.id}
                id={c.id}
                poster={c.poster_path}
                title={c.title || c.name}
                date={c.first_air_date || c.release_date}
                media_type={c.media_type}
                vote_average={c.vote_average}
                />
            ))}
            </div>
            
            <CustomPagination setPage={setPage} />

        </div>
```

**CUSTOM PAGINATION CODE**

```
    const handlePageChange = (page) => {
        setPage(page);
        window.scroll(0,0)
    }

    return (
        <div className='pagination-styles'>
            <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
            <Pagination count={pageNo} onChange={(e) => handlePageChange(e.target.textContent)} hideNextButton hidePrevButton />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
    )
```

**STYLING**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");

* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #191a19;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.seach-box-area {
  width: 100%;
}

.seach-box-searcher {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.trending-text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.trending {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.pagination-styles {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

**when pagination component is present**
[image: when pagination component is present]

**when pagination component is removed**
[image: when pagination component is removed]